# How to modify text when copyng to Clipboard using ZeroClipboard?

Tags: javascript, clipboard, zeroclipboard

I'm trying to use [zeroclipboard 2.2.0](http://zeroclipboard.org/).
This example copies div content to the Clipboard on button click.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/zeroclipboard/dist/ZeroClipboard.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input id="textholder" value="some text" />
<button id="button1" data-clipboard-target="textholder">Copy from div to Clipboard</button>

<script>
    var zeroClipboard = new ZeroClipboard();
    zeroClipboard.clip(document.querySelector("#button1"));
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

How to modify copied text in order to get, for example, "some text [copied]" instead of just "some text" on paste?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setText() function on your zeroClipboard, instead of just clipping the button. So you can create a variable where you get the text stored in your textfield and then modify it. This would be something like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/zeroclipboard/dist/ZeroClipboard.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input id="textholder" value="some text" />
<button id="button1" data-clipboard-target="textholder">Copy from div to Clipboard</button>

<script>
    var zeroClipboard = new ZeroClipboard();
    var text = //select your textfield and add modifications to the text
    zeroClipboard.setText(text);
    zeroClipboard.clip(document.querySelector("#button1"));
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps =)